# Inbox and content separation

Tags: interface

Is it worth for user experience to separate inbox items ( for example, orders ) and content items ( for example, tickets or discounts cards )?

Inbox items have two actions which are Accept and Decline ( user could add item or decline it ).

Content items have other actions that are neither Accept nor Decline.

Could you provide pros and contras for each solution below?

1. Inbox and content items are in one list.
2. Inbox and content items are in two lists, each list contain only one type of items.

According to me, second approach ( Separation ) gives user a great experience in 'todo' management. He saw a inbox items list and could check incomings easily. Also he could work with them like 'Accept all' or 'Decline all'. And, of course, he could save time in Inbox cleaning.

Comment: this would be very hard to implement because you would have to analyse the content and figure out if the content needed an action. I think its a neat idea but very hard to make happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is the best approach and Google's [Priority Inbox](http://lifehacker.com/5992588/gmails-priority-inbox-is-awesome-just-give-it-a-chance) is a great example of what you are likely trying to implement.

[image]

This is a great idea and it helps the user prioritize the emails to be responded first.

[image]

Even Microsoft's outlook has a similar feature 'focused' and 'others' tabs for separating the emails on priority.

[image]